# How to Replace a part of string in Left Join Statement in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

I have sql statement

```
 LEFT JOIN SeniorCitizen on FinishedTransaction.SCID = SeniorCitizen.OSCAID
```

SCID has 1234
OSCAID has 1234/102938

How can I remove /102938 so that it matches

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: Consider re-designing you db. Problems like this are usually consequences of bad design.

Comment: are you still trying to figure this out or do you have it working now?

Answer (score 3):

Hmmm, one method is to use `LIKE`:

```
ON SeniorCitizen.OSCAID LIKE FinishedTransaction.SCID + '/%'
```

No guarantees on performance, but this should do the `join` correctly.

EDIT:

You can do this operation efficiently by using a computed column and then an index on the computed column.

So:

```
alter table SeniorCitizen
    add OSCAIDshort as ( cast(left(OSCAID, CHARINDEX('/', OSCAID) - 1) as int) );

create index idx_SeniorCitizen_OSCAIDshort on SeniorCitizen(OSCAIDshort);
```

(The cast presumes that the SCID column is an integer.)

Then you can use this in the join as:

```
LEFT JOIN SeniorCitizen on FinishedTransaction.SCID = SeniorCitizen.OSCAIDshort
```

This formulation can use the index on the computed column and hence is probably the fastest way to do the `join`.

Comment: is this applicable to vb 6 and recordset?

Comment: If you are using a SQL query for the interface to the database, then this is applicable.

Answer (score 1):

If you knew that the length of the numbers you were comparing was always 4, you could use `SUBSTRING`, like so:

```
LEFT JOIN SeniorCitizen on FinishedTransaction.SCID = SUBSTRING(SeniorCitizen.OSCAID, 1, 4)
```

to just grab the first four characters from `OSCAID` for the comparison.

However, even if you knew the length was always 4, it's still safer to assume that you won't know the length, because maybe at some point in the future the length grows. And if it does, your query can scale with it with no issues. To do this, you can use a combination of `SUBSTRING` and `CHARINDEX`, like so:

```
LEFT JOIN SeniorCitizen on FinishedTransaction.SCID = SUBSTRING(SeniorCitizen.OSCAID, 1, CHARINDEX('/', SeniorCitizen.OSCAID, 0))
```

This will start at the first character in `OSCAID` and continue reading until it finds a `/`. So if the string is `1234/102938`, it'll return `1234`. And if grows to `123456/102938`, it'll return `123456`.

Be sure to check out the docs for each of those functions to get a better understanding of their capabilities:

**SUBSTRING:** https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx

**CHARINDEX:** https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx

Comment: SUBSTRING's not SARGable, for all but the smallest datasets you're better off materializing or computing the substring you want to search on into its own column.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use `LEFT` or `SUBSTRING` Functions to do this.

```
SUBSTRING(SeniorCitizen.OSCAID, 1, 4)

LEFT(SeniorCitizen.OSCAID, 4)
```

But keep in mind that, usage of user defined functions might make the query non-sargable.